# Skip POJO field while serializing to JSON using GSON for specific case when POJO itself is field of another POJO

Tags: java, json, kotlin, gson, pojo

I have a `Person` data class in Kotlin like this

```kotlin
data class Person(
    val name: String,
    val age: Int,
    val gender: String,
    val city: String? = null,
    val state: String? = null,
    val country: String? = null
)
```

And a `Family` data class like this

```kotlin
data class Family (
    val headPerson: Person,
    val spouse: Person,
    val children: List<Person>
)
```

Then I created `Family` object like this

```kotlin
val headPerson = Person("Head Person", 46, "Male", "Mumbai", "Maharashtra", "India")
val spouse = Person("Spouse", 42, "Female", "Mumbai", "Maharashtra", "India")
val child1 = Person("Child 1", 16, "Male", "Delhi", "Delhi", "India")
val child2 = Person("Child 2", 22, "Female", "Hyderabad", "Telangana", "India")

val family = Family(headPerson, spouse, listOf(child1, child2))
```

Then I created JSON using GSON like this:-

```kotlin
val familyJson = Gson().toJson(family)
```

The JSON that I got was this

```json
{
  "children": [
    {
      "age": 16,
      "city": "Delhi",
      "country": "India",
      "gender": "Male",
      "name": "Child 1",
      "state": "Delhi"
    },
    {
      "age": 22,
      "city": "Hyderabad",
      "country": "India",
      "gender": "Female",
      "name": "Child 2",
      "state": "Telangana"
    }
  ],
  "headPerson": {
    "age": 46,
    "city": "Mumbai",
    "country": "India",
    "gender": "Male",
    "name": "Head Person",
    "state": "Maharashtra"
  },
  "spouse": {
    "age": 42,
    "city": "Mumbai",
    "country": "India",
    "gender": "Female",
    "name": "Spouse",
    "state": "Maharashtra"
  }
}
```

But what I want is something like this (Serialize `age` and `name` only in case of Spouse and Children):-

```json
{
  "children": [
    {
      "age": 16,
      "name": "Child 1"
    },
    {
      "age": 22,
      "name": "Child 2"
    }
  ],
  "headPerson": {
    "age": 46,
    "city": "Mumbai",
    "country": "India",
    "gender": "Male",
    "name": "Head Person",
    "state": "Maharashtra"
  },
  "spouse": {
    "age": 42,
    "name": "Spouse"
  }
}
```

I tried `excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation()` (Annotated fields to be serialized with `@Expose`) and `setExclusionStrategies()` (Annotated fields not to be serialized with custom annotation) provided in `GsonBuilder()` class but then it's getting applied for all cases including headPerson also

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Exclude a Kotlin data class property/field from serialization/deserialization using gson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53425600/exclude-a-kotlin-data-class-property-field-from-serialization-deserialization-us)

Comment: If the address part is common to the whole family, why not put it on the Family level? The thing you want to have seems pretty confusing to me. Also, it seems the data is actually different for some children, is it expected to lose this data when serialized?

Comment: Nope Joffrey, members of family can have different address but only while serializing I want the Json to be in particular format

Comment: @LuisCardozaBird as I explained in the question I tried various methods but it's getting applied for all fields. I think I need some kind of custom `Serializer` but I'm confused how to do that.

Comment: @AyushVipul I think you haven't read my question carefully